# combine and aggregate data from structured numpy array to another

Tags: python, numpy, structured-array

I've got an empty structured array:

```
id_and_orders_type = np.dtype([('id', 'i4'), ('order_values', 'f4', (100,))])
id_and_orders = np.zeros((10,), dtype=id_and_orders_type)
```

and I've got another structured array with the data to be filled into `id_and_orders`.

```
orders_type = np.dtype([('id', 'i4'), ('value', 'f4')])
orders = np.array(((1, 33.2), (2, 37.1), (3, 22.1), (2, 63.9), (3, 93.1)), dtype=orders_type)
```

what I wanna do now is to map every `orders['value']` with its corresponding `id` in `id_and_orders`. In a way that `id_and_orders` would contain `orders['id']` with a subarray of the values for that id in `orders`:

```
id_and_orders = np.array(((1, (33.2,), (2, (37.1, 63.9), (3, (22.1, 93.1)))
```

and maybe some would know how to build the size of the subarray `id_and_orders['order_values']` dynamically and not fixed sized with 100.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a Pandas DataFrame instead:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
    [(1, 33.2), (2, 37.1), (3, 22.1), (2, 63.9), (3, 93.1)],
    columns=['type', 'value']
)
#    type  value
# 0     1   33.2
# 1     2   37.1
# 2     3   22.1
# 3     2   63.9
# 4     3   93.1
```

which then easily lets you group by `type`, and e.g. take the sum of `value`s

```
df.groupby('type').sum()
#       value
# type       
# 1      33.2
# 2     101.0
# 3     115.2
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it also possible to have the values within a subseries rather than the sum of them?

Comment: No. But what would be the point in that anyways? You're grouping them so you can do processing on them, not just to group them and leave them there.

Comment: Because I need to visualize every single value and I want to access the data via the id. It's actually an order_book.

Comment: Again, something you can easily do in Pandas. It is the right tool for the job!

Answer (score 0):

This is something I'd write using python data structures, and only consider converting some of the data structures to numpy if performance becomes an issue.
`Numpy` allows for fast access on items of uniform type (and shape, for multidimensional data).
When data doesn't exactly match that format it's a good idea to consider incorporating `list`s and `dict`s.

Rather than an array, just use a list for input:

```
id_orders = [(1, 33.2), (2, 37.1), (3, 22.1), (2, 63.9), (3, 93.1)]
```

Then create a `dict` of orders by id, with each key containing a list of values belonging to that key.

```
orders = {}
for id, val in id_orders:
    orders.setdefault(id, []).append(val)
```

Using `setdefault` returns the current value for a key if the key is present.
If it is not it sets the key as an empty list and returns that.
Once `orders` has been initialized it's simple enough to convert each entry to a `numpy` array.
Do this step last, since `numpy` arrays don't handle changes in size very well.

```
orders = {k:array(v) for k, v in orders.items()}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but this is only a small example on a bigger Problem. Actually there are 15 Columns and 50.000 Rows and Sub-Frames.

Comment: 15 columns you want to use as an id, or 15 columns you want stored?

Comment: This will work fine even with much larger data than the example.  My computer runs 50,000 rows with 1000 unique ids in 16ms.

Comment: Sure, but I've got multi dimensional subframes within these values and there will be the need of multiple and high frequence queries on the data

Comment: And this solution can't handle that because?  You're trying to fit numpy into a problem it wasn't designed for.  It will be substantially more difficult (and possibly slower) in the end than using the data types that python provides (or a proper database, which seems to be what you're trying to create).